# Avoiding repetitive javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox

I have a HTML form with about 30 similar lines in it. Each line is something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Car Park</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="local_parking" name="amenity[]" value="local_parking"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="local_parking_t" name="amenity_text[]" value="Car park"></td>
</tr>
```

If the checkbox is not checked, the text box needs to be disabled to avoid it passing its value to the mySQL query that follows. I can do that for one line with this javascript:

```
document.getElementById('local_parking').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('local_parking_t').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

However it seems unreasonably messy to repeat the javascript 30 times over with different IDs. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch every `checkbox` and bind `change` event listener. If user checks specified `checkbox` - enable corresponding `text` input.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    
    [...checkboxes].forEach((v,i) => v.addEventListener('change', function(){
      inputs[i].disabled = !this.checked;
    }));
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>Car Park</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="local_parking" name="amenity[]" value="local_parking"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="local_parking_t" disabled name="amenity_text[]" value="Car park"></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td>Some txt</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="local_parking" name="amenity[]" value="local_parking"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="local_parking_t" disabled name="amenity_text[]" value="Car "></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. You are indeed a "kind user". I was able to drop the ids as they were only there for the purpose of my javascript. There is just one tiny problem: Dreamweaver throws up a highlight suggesting a problem with the line beginning "Array". I can't see it though. Any ideas?

Comment: @TrapezeArtist Array.from is a ES6 feature, might be unaccessible on e.g. IE 7. You can use spread operator instead. Check it now.

Comment: Both versions seem to work perfectly, but Dreamweaver still doesn't like it. It's CS5.5 so perhaps there's something new in there that it doesn't recognise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common class to target the `CHECKBOX` element then DOM traversal method to target the `INPUT` element.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.local_parking');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].disabled = !this.checked;
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Car Park</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="local_parking" name="amenity[]" value="local_parking"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="local_parking_t" name="amenity_text[]" value="Car park" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car Park</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="local_parking" name="amenity[]" value="local_parking"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="local_parking_t" name="amenity_text[]" value="Car park" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```